# How to check if my EditText has a TextChangedListener (TextWatcher)?

Tags: android, listener, textwatcher, textchanged

I know we can add a `TextWatcher` to `EditTexts` using `addTextChangedListener` and remove it using `removeTextChangedListener`. But now I want to check if my `EditText` has any `TextWatcher` or not.

How can I do that?

I have a grid. It has an adapter. My adapter checks if the type of defined item is EditText add a `TextWatcher` to it. When method `getView` is called `TextWatcher` is added to that `EditText`. I want to avoid adding extra `TextWatchers` if one is added.

Comment: What the is objective of the this.  There might be a more straight forward way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you properly use `convertView` in your adapter, you can easily ensure that only one TextWatcher is added to each EditText. (`if(convertView == null) /* Inflate a view and add a TextWatcher */`)

Comment: @mrres1 I do. So the EditText Exists. after your line of code, I add my TextWatcher. So it gets extra TextWatchers every time the Grid is refreshed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is work around , you can set tag to your edittext inside getview method using `setTag` method of View , before doing this check if getTag is not null if so you have already set `TextWatcher`...

if(editText object getTag is null then editText.seTtag and add watcher) 
else return

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to do this specifically. Why not maintain a boolean variable, say `textWatch` yourself?

Every time you set a watcher, set this to true and set it to false when the watcher is removed.

You can simply check this variable to see if the editText has a watcher or not.

You can use an array of booleans if you have more than one editText boxes that need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Map` to store all the `EditText` objects that have `TextWatcher`'s

For example

```
Map<EditText, Boolean> textWatcherMap = new HashMap<>();
```

When you add the `TextWatcher` to the `EditText`, add its reference to the `HashMap`.

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher(..);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
textWatcherMap.put(editText, true);
```

Then when you are working on the `EditText`, check the `HashMap` for the reference

```
if(textWatcherMap.get(editText) != null)
    useCurrentTextWatcher();
else 
{
    addNewTextWatcher();
    textWatcherMap.put(editText, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call

```
edittext.removeTextChangedListener(YourWatcherObject)
```

before every time you add a new watcher so that it can't have more than one watcher

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(YourWatcherObject)
```

Comment: very strange solution